# Get orders where order lines meet certain requirements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following simplified tables:

**tblOrders**

```
orderID    date
---------------------
1          2013-10-04
2          2013-10-05
3          2013-10-06
```

**tblOrderLines**

```
lineID     orderID     ProductCategory
--------------------------------------
1          1           10
2          1           3
3          1           10
4          2           3
5          3           3
6          3           10
7          3           10
```

I want to select records from tblOrders ONLY if any order line has ProductCategory = 10. So, if none of the lines of a particular order has ProductCategory = 10, then do not return that order.

How would I do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Hrm, guess it's been too long to edit my comment? Lots of answers below.  I would also suggest a SQL tutorial, what you're asking is very basic.  [Clicky!](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/)

Comment: Just curious, why would you choose to accept the later of two virtually identical answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use exists for this

```
Select o.*
From tblOrders o
Where exists (
    Select 1
    From tblOrderLines ol
    Where ol.ProductCategory = 10
    And ol.OrderId = o.OrderId
)
```

Answer (score 6):

This should do:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblOrders O
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tblOrderLines
             WHERE ProductCategory = 10
             AND OrderID = O.OrderID)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT orderId
FROM tblOrders t1
INNER JOIN tblOrderLines t2 ON t1.orderId = t2.orderId
WHERE t2.ProductCategory = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblOrders O
    JOIN tblOrderLines L
    ON O.orderID = L.orderID
WHERE L.OrderID in (SELECT orderID FROM tblOrderLines WHERE ProductCategory = 10)
```

Comment: Dont think you need the join here